# How to persist data using Realm Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, realm

When the app is closed, data in Realm is disappeared.

Code is this.(reference: https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/)

```
// Persist your data easily
Dog *mydog = [[Dog alloc] init];
RLMRealm *realm = [RLMRealm defaultRealm];
[realm transactionWithBlock:^{
  [realm addObject:mydog];
}];
```

Sorry for the newbie question but I'm in a trouble.
If you can give me any advice or tips, please tell me. I would really appreciate it.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Up-voted for having a `Dog` class and a `mydog` instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're playing with Realm in any of the sample app code provided, there's usually [a line of code at the start of the app](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/blob/master/examples/ios/objc/Simple/AppDelegate.m#L50) that deletes the default Realm file on disk each time the app is launched. This is so the features of Realm can be demonstrated each time the app is launched, and not just the first time.

As long as the `default.realm` file isn't being modified by something else on app launch, you shouldn't be experiencing data loss each time (That would be an absolutely terrible database!).